# Sql group data ?combine?

Tags: sql, group-by

if I type

```
SELECT petid1, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid1 !=0 GROUP BY petid1
ORDER BY total DESC
```

it will output the following data

[image]

if I type

```
SELECT petid2, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid2 !=0 GROUP BY petid2
ORDER BY total DESC
```

it will output the following data

[image]

How can I group the same is result?
such as petid1=1218 total result + petid2=1218 total result  =20+9=29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the resulting queries and combine the totals. Not sure what database you are using, but should be something like this:

```
SELECT petid1, petid2, (a.total + b.total) as combinedtotal
FROM
    (SELECT petid1, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid1 !=0 GROUP BY petid1) a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT petid2, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid2 !=0 GROUP BY petid2) b
ON a.petid1 = b.petid2
ORDER BY combinedtotal DESC
```

This will only return those records that have a matching petid1 and petid2, so in your example, id's 1240 and 995 would not show. If you want these records displayed, change the join to a FULL JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the two outputs that you are trying to combine. Since these are two separate pieces of information, you will need to use both of the queries in your question. By using a `union all`, you can combine them into one table.

```
SELECT petid1 as petid, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid1 !=0 GROUP BY petid1
Union all
SELECT petid2 as petid, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid2 !=0 GROUP BY petid2
```

The output of this query would be

> ```
> petid | total
> 1218  | 20
> 9102  | 18
> 995   | 10
> 1238  | 9
> 1217  | 8
> 912   | 10
> 1218  | 9
> 1238  | 8
> 1240  | 6
> 1217  | 5
> ```

Now, in order to combine the petid, you need to make the above query into a subquery and move the group by to the outside query.

```
Select petid, count(*) as total
From(
    SELECT petid1 as petid FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid1 !=0 
    Union all
    SELECT petid2 as petid FROM cdc_padchat WHERE petid2 !=0
)
GROUP BY petid
Order by total desc
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't know what error ,but when i use the statment I cannot run out the result.....

Comment: A union does not give the OP an ability to compare the results on the first half of your answer.  And count does not add as OP requests on the second half.

Comment: @paqogomez The OP only specified that he wanted the totals for the petid, i.e. for id 1218, total result =20+9=29. The count will return the same as a sum since there is no group by in the subquery and I used a union all. If the OP wants to see the output from the first half of my answer, then they should run that query.